# Running NLP model using flask API vs running model on Spyder

Tags: python, flask

I am running NLP based clustering model on Spyder and also running the same model using FLASK API and I have used multiprocessing Pool concept to run the same model for different data in parallel. 
I have observed that when I run my model on Spyder ,it takes less time than running the same model in FLASK API and the time variation is huge.
Lets say when I run the model on Sypder alone , it takes 2 hours but the same model took 4 hours when run through FLASK API.
I am just wondering why this is happening as the FLASK API hit the same model function which i used to run on spyder ?

Answer (score 0):

threaded defaults to True as of Flask 1.0, so for the latest versions of Flask, the default development server will be able to serve multiple clients simultaneously by default. For older versions of Flask, you can explicitly pass threaded=True to enable this behavior.

For example, you can do

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(threaded=True)
```

to handle multiple clients using threads in a way compatible with old Flask versions, or

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(threaded=False, processes=3)
```

Comment: I used `app.run(threaded=False, processes=3)` and getting  `ValueError: Your platform does not support forking.`

Comment: This means that your OS does not support this. Did you try the first approach? OR you can try this https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/3fr2a8/windows_alternative_to_gunicorn_deploying_on/

Comment: I tried first approach,but that takes much time to execute the job which does not solve my issue.